# Data Validation - Using truth table to define list options

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a worksheet where I would like two drop down lists, one for screw size, and one for screw length. Only certain lengths are available for each size, so I want the length drop down to read the values from a truth table to see which lengths are available to show in the list.

I've gotten the desired result, but it requires making a named list for every screw size and using the actual values in the list. I'd prefer the table to just be TRUE/FALSE with no need to create named lists as this will need to scale and be used for many types of screws.

This picture should explain, I've attached the spreadsheet as well.

[Data Validation Truth Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVf38.png)
[Data Validation Truth Table File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqtginedfdq18q1/Data%20Validation%20Truth%20Table.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1449808/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far?

Comment: You need dependent drop down rather than standard!! What formula you have used getting TRUE!